# EDX set 5 - caesars cipher

Tags: python

I am doing edx problem set 5 and I stumbled upon a problem in my code:

```
# 6.00x Problem Set 5
#
# Part 1 - HAIL CAESAR!

import string
import random

WORDLIST_FILENAME = "words.txt"

# -----------------------------------
# Helper code
# (you don't need to understand this helper code)
def loadWords():
    """
    Returns a list of valid words. Words are strings of lowercase letters.

    Depending on the size of the word list, this function may
    take a while to finish.
    """
    print "Loading word list from file..."
    inFile = open(WORDLIST_FILENAME, 'r')
    wordList = inFile.read().split()
    print "  ", len(wordList), "words loaded."
    return wordList

def isWord(wordList, word):
    """
    Determines if word is a valid word.

    wordList: list of words in the dictionary.
    word: a possible word.
    returns True if word is in wordList.

    Example:
    >>> isWord(wordList, 'bat') returns
    True
    >>> isWord(wordList, 'asdf') returns
    False
    """
    word = word.lower()
    word = word.strip(" !@#$%^&*()-_+={}[]|\\:;'<>?,./\"")
    return word in wordList

def randomWord(wordList):
    """
    Returns a random word.

    wordList: list of words  
    returns: a word from wordList at random
    """
    return random.choice(wordList)

def randomString(wordList, n):
    """
    Returns a string containing n random words from wordList

    wordList: list of words
    returns: a string of random words separated by spaces.
    """
    return " ".join([randomWord(wordList) for _ in range(n)])

def randomScrambled(wordList, n):
    """
    Generates a test string by generating an n-word random string
    and encrypting it with a sequence of random shifts.

    wordList: list of words
    n: number of random words to generate and scamble
    returns: a scrambled string of n random words

    NOTE:
    This function will ONLY work once you have completed your
    implementation of applyShifts!
    """
    s = randomString(wordList, n) + " "
    shifts = [(i, random.randint(0, 25)) for i in range(len(s)) if s[i-1] == ' ']
    return applyShifts(s, shifts)[:-1]

def getStoryString():
    """
    Returns a story in encrypted text.
    """
    return open("story.txt", "r").read()


# (end of helper code)
# -----------------------------------


#
# Problem 1: Encryption
#
def buildCoder(shift):
    """
    Returns a dict that can apply a Caesar cipher to a letter.
    The cipher is defined by the shift value. Ignores non-letter characters
    like punctuation, numbers and spaces.

    shift: 0 <= int < 26
    returns: dict
    """
    dict={}
    upper = string.ascii_uppercase
    lower = string.ascii_lowercase
    for l in range(len(upper)):
        dict[upper[l]] = upper[(l+shift)%len(upper)]
    for l in range(len(lower)):
        dict[lower[l]] = lower[(l+shift)%len(lower)]
    return dict


def applyCoder(text, coder):
    """
    Applies the coder to the text. Returns the encoded text.

    text: string
    coder: dict with mappings of characters to shifted characters
    returns: text after mapping coder chars to original text
    """
    new_text=''
    for l in text:
        if not(l in string.punctuation or l == ' ' or l in str(range(10))):
           new_text += coder[l]
        else:
           new_text += l            
    return new_text   

def applyShift(text, shift):
    """
    Given a text, returns a new text Caesar shifted by the given shift
    offset. Lower case letters should remain lower case, upper case
    letters should remain upper case, and all other punctuation should
    stay as it is.

    text: string to apply the shift to
    shift: amount to shift the text (0 <= int < 26)
    returns: text after being shifted by specified amount.
    """
    ### TODO.
    ### HINT: This is a wrapper function.
    coder=buildCoder(shift)
    return applyCoder(text,coder)

#
# Problem 2: Decryption
#
def findBestShift(wordList, text):
    """
    Finds a shift key that can decrypt the encoded text.

    text: string
    returns: 0 <= int < 26
    """
    ### TODO
    wordsFound=0
    bestShift=0

    for i in range(26):
        currentMatch=0
        encrypted=applyShift(text,i)
        lista=encrypted.split(' ')
        for w in lista: 
            if isWord(wordList,w):
                currentMatch+=1
        if currentMatch>wordsFound:
                currentMatch=wordsFound
                bestShift=i
    return bestShift

def decryptStory():
    """
    Using the methods you created in this problem set,
    decrypt the story given by the function getStoryString().
    Use the functions getStoryString and loadWords to get the
    raw data you need.

    returns: string - story in plain text
    """
    text = getStoryString()
    bestMatch = findBestShift(loadWords(), text)
    return applyShift(text, bestMatch)

#
# Build data structures used for entire session and run encryption
#

if __name__ == '__main__':
    wordList = loadWords()
    decryptStory()

s = 'Pmttw, ewztl!'
print findBestShift(wordList, s)

print decryptStory()
```

The problem is that the single module of the program works apart from decrypt story. What is the problem in that piece of code?

Comment: *How* does the decrypt not work? Do you get an error? If so, what error do you see? If not, what input do you give it, what do you expect to see and what do you get instead? Can you reduce your code to just the part that shows the problem?

Comment: What is edx problem set 5? Is that something from your school/university or is it something we're expected to know?

Comment: @jleahy: EDX was the OS on the old IBM minis. Which makes me think the answer really should be in EDL, PL/I, or COBOL, because I don't think anyone ever ported Python to the Series/1. Plus, it should be using EBCDIC rather than ASCII.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that `applyCoder` can't work as written.

`buildCoder` builds a `dict` that only has entries for letters. But `applyCoder` tries to look up anything that's not `in string.punctuation`, or `== ' '`, or `in str(range(10))`. I think you wanted `string.digits` there (because `str(range(10))` is `'[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]'`), but it's still going to blow up if you give it, say, a newline, which a file called `story.txt` is almost guaranteed to have.

The simple fix is to just check for `l in string.ascii_uppercase or l in string.ascii_lowercase`. But there's an even better fix: Instead of trying to come up with a convoluted way to express the same filter in reverse, or repeating yourself, just try it:

```
for l in text:
    new_text += coder.get(l, l)
```

This will return `coder[l]` if `l` is in the map, or the default value, `l`, if it's not.

---

Having fixed that, the function runs, and successfully outputs something. But it doesn't output the *right* something. Why?

Well, look at this:

```
if currentMatch>wordsFound:
    currentMatch=wordsFound
    bestShift=i
```

So, every time you find a better match than the initial `wordsFound` of 0, you… throw away the `currentMatch` value and leave `wordsFound` untouched. Surely you wanted `wordsFound = currentMatch`, not the other way around, right?

---

Having fixed both of these problems:

```
$ ln -s /usr/share/dict/words words.txt
$ echo -e "This is a test.\n\nIs it good enough? Let's see.\n" | rot13 > story.txt
$ python caesar.py
Loading word list from file...
   235886 words loaded.
Loading word list from file...
   235886 words loaded.
18
Loading word list from file...
   235886 words loaded.
This is a test. 

Here's some text. Is it enough? Let's see.
```

So, it's obviously doing some unnecessary repetitive work somewhere, but other than that, it works.

---

It's probably more important to learn how to debug problems like this yourself than to get the answer to this problem, so here's a couple of suggestions.

I found the problems by adding some extra `print` statements. The important one is here:

```
if currentMatch>wordsFound:
    print i, currentMatch, wordsFound
    currentMatch=wordsFound
    bestShift=i
```

You'll see that `wordsFound` never changes from 0. And that it picks a shift with 1 match as the best even after having found one with 18 matches. So obviously, something is wrong.

But I didn't know where to put that one. I added a dozen or so `print` lines all over the place. That's the simplest way to debug simple code.

For more complex code, where there's just way too much to print, you may want to write to a log file (ideally using `logging`) that you can parse after the fact. Or, better, use much simpler input data, and run in the debugger and/or an interactive visualizer (like [this one](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#)).

Or, better, strip things down until you find the part that doesn't work. For example, if you know that shift 18 should be better than shift 12, try calling `applyShift` with 12 and 18 and see what they each return.

Even if these steps don't get you to the answer, they will get you to a better question to post on SO.